# Play and Seek Audio File in java

Tags: java, audio, playback, seek, javasound

I used [this](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml) class to play my Wav file.

Its very good but How to start my wav file on some position (KB or second)?

```
auline.start();
    int nBytesRead = 0;
    byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];



    try {
        while (nBytesRead != -1) {
            nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
            System.out.println("s");
            if (nBytesRead >= 0)
                auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    } finally {
        auline.drain();
        auline.close();
    }
```

This is part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Clip`(1) makes it easy to start a sound from wherever is needed (in seconds).  For an example see the `Clip` code in the [JavaSound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

1. See especially.

   - [Clip.setMicrosecondPosition(long)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setMicrosecondPosition%28long%29). *"Sets the media position in microseconds."*
   - [Clip.setFramePosition(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setFramePosition%28int%29) *"Sets the media position in sample frames."*
   - [Clip.setLoopPoints(int,int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setLoopPoints(int,%20int)). *"Sets the first and last sample frames that will be played in the loop."*

Answer (score 0):

Use this value `offset` :

***`0 < offset < lengthOfArray`***

so it will start reading from the current value of offset and hence write only the read data. Now you are using the value of `offset = 0`

`auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead)` **--- >**  `auline.write(abData, offset, nBytesRead)`

where `offset` is greater than 0 but less than `nBytesRead`
See the Doc [#write(byte[], int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Yes I tried    auline.write(abData, EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE*(n), nBytesRead); but It isnt work, And I get error... Now I am using Clip and its working Thank you for reply

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:199)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream.read(AudioInputStream.java:275)
        at akorbulsoundrecorder.AePlayWave.run(AePlayWave.java:90)

Comment: how did you actually implement the statement `nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
` after i gave you the answer?