# I would like this music file to continue playing the music where it left off

Tags: java

In this program I would like 4 different songs to be played at once and turned off with a toggle. I've gotten the program to work with one song but I don't know how to implement in such a way where it'll start the song up again because you had not pressed the stop button before ending of the program. I've never worked with .txt files before in java but I know they handle this kind of thing.

THE PROGRAMS GUI (Just two buttons, but more will be added)

[image: The Program GUI]

THE CODE

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class AddSound extends JFrame {
    // JButton Play = new JButton("Play"); The old Play button that only played
    // it once
    JButton Loop = new JButton("Play");
    JButton Stop = new JButton("Stop");

URL music1 = AddSound.class.getResource("music1.wav");
AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(music1);

public AddSound() {
    super("AddingSound");

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    /*
     * THIS ONLY THE PLAYS THE SONG TILL THE ENDING
     * Play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void
     * actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { clip.play(); }
     * 
     * });
     */

    Loop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clip.loop();
        }

    });

    Stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            clip.stop();
        }

    });
    // add(Play); To add the Play button
    add(Loop);
    add(Stop);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new AddSound();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java.applet.AudioClip you are using doesn't support playing audio from the specific position.

You may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950626/play-and-seek-audio-file-in-java) post.

When you manage to find out how to play sound with microseconds position, you may want to use [window closing event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) to write to file where your audio should start next time your program runs.

Writing to files is easy part, you can use [BufferedWriter](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/).

Comment: Dude thank you soooo much. This is like the third time I've requested this answer and everyone is so anal about it well not everyone but most. You really helped me there :D